What is the equivalent of GitHub Actions "with:" in GitLab CI/CD?
In GitHub, this works:
uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
with:
  host: 10.10.10.10
  username: user

In GitLab, this produces error:
image: appleboy/drone-ssh
variables:
   host: 10.10.10.10
   username: user

The error:
Error: missing server host

I have read the following Docs:
GitHub Syntax of 'with'
It said it is for 'set as environment variables'. So I assume the 'variables:' key is for the equivalent function. However, it is not.
So, if it is setting the environment variables, I try:
before_script:
- export host=$DEPLOY_HOST
- export username=$DEPLOY_USERNAME

But it produce the same error.

There's no direct replacement. with sets variables for a GitHub Action. In GitLab CI, you don't have this "Action" concept (yet), you use a container image directly. You'd have to see what the container image expects as (environment) variables. Likely the GitHub Action variables map to a container environment variable with slightly different names.
